# How can I fix the new white border in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gui

I am using Google Chrome 117.0.5938.132 (64 bits) and Ubuntu 23.04.
After an update in the operating system, Google Chrome has a white border.
This hadn't happened before, even when I was using gtk+ and a custom color.
Is there a reason for this? Can you help me fix it? Thank you

Screenshot showing the white border:
[image: Screenshot showing the white border]

Comment: Does it look better if you enable the **Use system title bar and borders** option in Chrome settings?

Comment: I am sorry but it is extremely hard for me to see the white border going all the way around the window there.  I brought up my Chrome browser and places where I could see darker colors the tiny 1 px border seemed to be more white so that I could differentiate where one window stopped and the other began.  But, if you do find the border annoying you might need to file a bug with Google since it may not be following your theme.

Comment: +1 I also noticed this ugly white border (Ubuntu 20.04). It is especially visible when the backdrop is dark. I do not want to enable system titlebar because it looks even worse.

Answer (score 3):

I had quite similar problem. It seems that the reason was something related to the custom colors I used. I was able to fix it by going to `chrome://settings/appearance` and changing the theme to `Classic`. `GTK` seems to work also.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was able to get rid of the white border by setting up Picom and disabling shadows.

Picom was already installed on my system, so I grabbed a copy of the [default config file](https://github.com/yshui/picom/blob/next/picom.sample.conf) from Picom's GitHub repo, and copied it to `~/.config/picom.conf`

I then set `shadows = false` to disable the shadows around the menu.

Finally, I configured Picom to start on system startup. I'm on Lubuntu with LXQt so I followed [these instructions](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/First_step_with_LXQt):

> To make Picom start automatically at login : LXQt Control Center -> LXQt Settings -> Session Settings -> Autostart -> Add Name: Picom, Command : picom.